# vs 2019 LNK2001 on c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I try 1 month now to create a desktop application on c++ but vs 2019 make your work hard....
Anyway the first time when i try to run my program after create a form i get thr error "entry poin must be defined" when i define the entry point to main i get this 2 error -> "LNK2001    unresolved external symbol _main" + " 1 unresolved externals " + 1 windows popup box when says " unable to start program (path of my project folder + projectname.exe file"

Comment: ***unable to start program (path of my project folder + projectname.exe file"*** If the project does not build an executable you will not be able to run it.

Comment: ***"LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _main" + " 1 unresolved externals "*** Did you create an `int main()` function? If you did is it in a source file that is part of your project? If you have no `int main()` function why don't you? Did you want to create a console application or GUI one using standard c++ (not .net /CLR)?

Comment: If you are programming in the windows api directly and not using .net or MFC or some other framework you should start by reading this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X) "Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition (Developer Reference) 5th Edition by Charles Petzold"